# Dice Probability: One event happening before another

Tags: probability, dice

A fair die is continuously thrown, what is the probability that a number divisible by two is thrown before a number that is divisible by three is thrown?

The answer is 0.6, but I'm somehow unable to understand why. I assumed that to achieve the above, one cannot throw a 6, and hence, as the numbers that are to be considered here would be {2,3,4,6}, and what I got was 2/4, which isn't correct. Would be grateful if someone could give me pointers/tell me what the correct way to calculate this is! Thank you!

Comment: $2,4$ are divisible by two but not by $3$.  $3$ is divisible by three but not by two, and $6$ is divisible by both.  We can ignore tosses of $1$ or $5$ so the only question is, which of $2,3,4,6$ comes first.  As two of those cases are winners, and the rest losers, the answer is $\frac 12$, as you say.  Why do you think the answer is $\frac 23$?

Comment: @lulu You were faster, I just wanted to post basically the same.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. Probably there is a mistake in either statement or answer.

Comment: @Peter  I can't get $.6$ at all...You could claim $\frac 34$ if you allow $6$ as a winner.  But $.6$?

Comment: The trap is that one might think that there are $3$ even numbers but only $2$ divisible by $3$. But the point is, if $6$ appears first, the event does NOT happen. I think, this is the reason for the wrong solution $\frac{3}{5}$

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought the answer was correct since there were people who seemed to get the same answer as the answer key. However, I think that there is a chance that I'm holding the older version of the textbook and the answer key is not updated...

Comment: The Monty Hall problem shows that traps can occur everywhere in probability theory and that we are "probability-blind" , our intuition often leads to wrong conclusions. And here, we also must be careful with the $6$, I think many people would fall into this trap.